# How can i create my own world with some robot and control it with ROS?

Tags: ros, webots

I want to create my own world in webots and add a robot that i can control it with ROS. How can i do it? Is there any tutorial for that operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Webots tutorials here:

- https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorials

The first ones explain how to create your own simulation in Webots and create a controller and the last one is specific to ROS.